# Xterm with Solarized only showing dark background without font colors

Tags: debian, xterm, x-resources

I am trying to get the [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/xresources-colors-solarized) color scheme for xterm, but have not had much success with it. I am running Debian 6 and downloaded the `Xresources` to `~/.Xresources`.

After loading the new settings with `xrdb -load ~/.Xresources`, I get a XTerm with the blueish background from the theme, but no font colors.
[image: Xterm with solarized theme]

The default xterm is capable of color, as you can see below:
[image: default xterm with Debian]

How do I get the colors from solarized to show?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem here. The font colours are working (blue/light blue primarily).

Answer (score 6):

Your terminal is being colored by the new theme, as you can see from the new background and foreground colors. However, to make `ls` use more colors than the default set of colors, you should create a [`dir_colors`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) config file and let it be sourced from `~/.bashrc`. This file contains color and filetype pairs that are used to differentiate between different file types and their corresponding color to display. The environment variable `LS_COLORS` should hold this data after sourcing and `ls` will use this to display filenames accordingly.

The color code sequences used in `dir_colors` are equivalent to the `bash` escape codes for displaying text in colors -- `1;31` will be bold red; `0;31` will be normal red. Also, remember that these colors are always relative to the ones defined in `~/.Xresources` so the red color for instance, will correspond to `XTerm*color1` and so on.

Comment: https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized has this already setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding to my ~/.xinitrc this line:

```
export CLICOLOR=TRUE
```

Comment: Interesting, but could you expand on what does it affect exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Download extension for ls colors :

```
$ git clone git://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized.git
$ cp dircolors-solarized/dircolors.256dark .dircolors
```

`.bashrc` would automatic source `~/.dircolors`

Comment: Just to be clear: You don't have to source .dircolors in your .bashrc. As long as you copy the relevant file to ~/.dircolors, your bash should do the rest automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Put into `~./bashrc` this to load colors from your `.directory` file:

```
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]; then
[ -e "$HOME/.dircolors" ] && DIR_COLORS="$HOME/.dircolors"
[ -e "$DIR_COLORS" ] || DIR_COLORS=""
eval "`dircolors -b $DIR_COLORS`"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
fi
```